# Use existing identity provider in custom B2C policy

Tags: azure, azure-ad-b2c

We have been using an OpenID identity provider that we created on the identity providers page. This identity provider connects to our Azure AD.

We now have a need to switch over to a custom policy so that we can include some additinal information in the token that is retrieved from an azure function.

The issue is that even though we used the same openID connect information in the custom policy it is still seen as a new identity provider and any user that logs in will have a new user created and therefore a new OID.

We need them to log in with the same identity provider and use the same existing user/oid but going through our custom policy so we can add info into the token.

Answer (score 0):

I am assuming that you are adding Azure AD (**Single-Tenant**) IDP. So the metadata which you are adding is [https://login.microsoftonline.com/{tenant}/v2.0/.well-known/openid-configuration](https://login.microsoftonline.com/%7Btenant%7D/v2.0/.well-known/openid-configuration) . Replace {tenant} with your tenant value. Also, make sure in the custom policy you have the below configuration for UserID and identityprovider because in the AzureAD IDP flow it check based on alternativeSecurityID whether it is present in B2C tenant or not, if no then it creates a new ID or else it will pass ObjectID.

```
<OutputClaims>
<OutputClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="issuerUserId" PartnerClaimType="oid"/>
<OutputClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="identityProvider" PartnerClaimType="iss" />
</OutputClaims>
<OutputClaimsTransformations>
<OutputClaimsTransformation ReferenceId="CreateAlternativeSecurityId"/>
</OutputClaimsTransformations>
```

After Azure AD Authentication B2C Calls this Technical Profile to read the User Detail in B2C tenant:

```
<TechnicalProfile Id="AAD-UserReadUsingAlternativeSecurityId">
<Metadata>
<Item Key="Operation">Read</Item>
<Item Key="RaiseErrorIfClaimsPrincipalDoesNotExist">false</Item>
</Metadata>
<InputClaims>
<InputClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="AlternativeSecurityId" 
PartnerClaimType="alternativeSecurityId" Required="true" />
</InputClaims>
<OutputClaims>
<OutputClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="objectId" />
<OutputClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="userPrincipalName" />
<OutputClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="displayName" />
<OutputClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="otherMails" />
<OutputClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="givenName" />
<OutputClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="surname" />
</OutputClaims>
<IncludeTechnicalProfile ReferenceId="AAD-Common" />
</TechnicalProfile>
```

Comment: I am having this same issue and I have this setup in my custom policy but still an new account is created because the identity provider in my custom policy is not seen as the same provider as in the one I created previously in the GUI.